# Generate debug Apk from debug aab file is not working

Tags: java, android, apk, android-app-bundle, bundletool

I am using the following command to generate APK from the AAB file using the bundle tool.

I am using **bundletool-all-1.8.2.jar** downloaded from [here](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases)

I am using Windows 10 and **when I execute the following command, it didn't generate any APKS file but opened the bundletool-all-1.8.2.jar in WinRAR jar extractor**

```
C:/<Download location>/bundletool-all-1.8.2.jar build-apks --bundle=D:/app-debug.aab --output=D:/app-dev-debug.apks --mode=universal
```

Answer (score 0):

bundletool.jar is not an executable, it's a java archive, you need to run it using:

```
java -jar bundletool.jar [command] [parameters]
```

For convenience, you create an alias (Unix) or doskey (Windows) to create a shortcut so that typing `bundletool` expands to `java -jar bundletool.jar`.